# Does arcing with fluorescent lights indicate an open neutral?

Tags: electrical, wiring

i recently did some work on my house and had to disconnect the ground wire  from the water pipe before the water meter. I saw some arcing. I understand that it might be a open neutral.

I have three panel boxes one in my house and one in each one of my garages. I turned all breakers off and started to narrow it down. The fluorescent  lights in my garage were one that  made it spark. If I unplug the lights from the receptacle's the spark stops. I looked at all the grounds in the lights and there all appear good.

Also my boiler was a problem. I looked at the neutral in the box and they all seem tight.

Comment: That's certainly one way to find a ground fault.  The appliances causing current flow on your ground have a ground fault and are leaking current to actual earth/building steel/water pipes, or there is a serious wiring issue involving using a water pipe as neutral.  In the case of the fluorescent, just change the ballast, get a nice modern T8 ballast and 90CRI T8 actual tubes (not LED), you won't believe how nice everything looks under that light. Also switch it to a grounded cable of respectable length, if it doesn't have one.

Comment: the water pipe is copper , i bought the house 30 years ago new and that,s the way it was hooked up . from the meter in the house, since then two more panel boxes have been installed in each of my garages. I have 8 fluorescent lights hooked up in each garage . hooked into receptacle,s on the ceiling. when  i plug any one in it shows a ark? I checked all  receptacles with a tester and it shows it hooked up correctly ?

Comment: Gerald, I edited your post to remove the question marks you had on nearly every sentence. (Statements of opinion or assumption are not questions.) If any were actually intended to be questions, please edit them back in.

Comment: @isherwood bless you.

Answer (score 1):

This is a double problem.  It is a **ground fault** of the lights, which should normally be handled efficiently by the wired grounding system (and not the water pipe).  Unfortunately it is not, which reveals **faulty wiring**.

Normally, all current is supposed to return on the *neutral* wire, with wired grounding only as a safety shield.  The wired grounding is meant as a "catcher" to assure that any ground-fault current returns on the ground *wires* and does not resort to using water pipes etc.  Those should never come into play, not even in fault conditions.  The water pipe bonding (grounding electrode) exists to ground lightning and ESD, both *natural* electricity sources.

You can "kill the symptom" by fixing the ground-fault on the fluorescent lights.  But I wouldn't do that just yet.  I would use it as the "canary in the coal mine" to chase this problem.

### The real problem

Your ground wiring (or maybe neutral) is very broken.  First, check your neutrals for continuity.  I expect they are intact, as the water pipe/earth path is probably not capable of flowing enough current to power 8 fluorescent lights.  If you disconnect the water pipe strap, do the fluorescents in the garage go out?  If  you run a power tool also, do the fluorescents desperately flicker and the power tool stumble??  If those things work OK, that means the *neutral* system is probably intact.

Now onto the ground.  I expect ground defects, and realize this is not the end of the world -- **you can retrofit ground**.

First, I'd give a careful once-over to the main panel, just to make sure everything is in order.  Obviously your ground-bus to grounding-electrode strap is in good order, because removing it makes sparks, and that also proves the bond between your *ground bus* and your *neutral bus*.   In ***this*** main panel, you may see neutrals and grounds all jumbled together.  This is sloppy, but legal *in the main panel only* because there only, neutral and ground are bonded together.  That will not be the case in subpanels.

### The subpanels

The grounding here will be the crux of the matter. Correct is that the subpanel is fed from the main panel by 4 wires -- a ground, plus neutral, plus 2 hots - so 4 wires in total, with ground and neutral separate.  (occasionally you'll see only one hot; so one less wire).  The neutral and ground feeder go to separate neutral and ground bars, and those are isolated - they are not bonded, and any bonding straps or green screws are removed.  Each circuit has its neutral and ground going to separate bars.   That is *correct*.

However it's quite likely you will find 3 wires - 2 hots and a neutral.  One approach is to "bootleg ground", i.e. attach all the grounds to the neutral bar (like is done in a main panel). However, that would cause any fault current to return via neutral, which would **not** cause your symptom.

The other "3-wire" scenario is where the person *means well*, but doesn't understand the importance.  In this case, they correctly keep separate ground and neutral bars, and do not bootleg/bond ground to neutral (ok so far). But they fail to run a ground *wire* back to the main panel: they simply drive a ground rod into the dirt and attach the ground bus to that.  They expect *dirt* to carry back any fault currents to the main panel, via the main house's electrode.  That doesn't work.  Dirt is a very poor conductor, and will actually hide a dead-short *bolted fault* by not allowing enough current to flow for the breaker to trip.

I think that's the scenario you are going to find; either that or they did something much more awful, like abuse a water pipe as the subpanel ground rather than running a wire.  You don't want to flow current on pipes, unless you're really into galvanic corrosion and replacing pipes a lot.

The solution in any of these "3-wire" scenarios is to run a separate ground wire, and recent Code changes allow you to run *just* a ground wire.  The ground rod doesn't hurt, it's just no replacement for a ground wire.  The rod and wire do different jobs, and one can't do the other's.

### Fixing the ground faults

Every device is supposed to take power from "hot" and return it all to "neutral". When devices have insulation problems internally, they may start leaking power to other places they should not.  This would "electrify their metal chassis" and hurt people or start fires, if it was not for *grounding*.  This is why grounding exists.

I disagree with my colleague regarding the source of ground faults in fluorescents and other HID lighting.  Fluorescent lighting is commonly used in basement, garage and other utility space, all of which are protected by GFCI in a modern home.  It would be anathema for a modern electronic ballast to have any ground leakage, even 1ma, because with 10 fixtures, that would be 10ma, which exceeds the trip threshold of a GFCI.  I argue electronic ballasts are the *solution*, not the problem.  However, cruddy old *magnetic* ballasts (the heavy kind full of transformer windings and drippy tar - don't try to salvage one unless you really like tar) - those are highly prone to ground faults, in my experience.

You can switch to direct-wire LED "tubes" if you like, however I am not impressed with the build quality of the cheaper ones.  I am very impressed, however, with the quality and price of modern fluorescent ballasts and the latest tubes from mainline manufacturers.  As such, I am sticking to real fluorescent for now.  Get any respectable brand of electronic ballast that matches your light's wiring, then get nice 90 CRI tubes that match your ballast.  You will not believe how nice things look in that light.

Answer (score 0):

Other than what everyone has said above about making sure you are not using the ground as a neutral. If your fluorescent lights are using electronic ballasts you will pick up an arc if you disconnect your ground while it is in operation. This is caused by the electronics of LED drivers and electronic ballasts which delay the return current thus causing a harmonic. It has been a problem in engineering causing several different methods of wiring to change. Such as using a separate neutral for every lighting circuit instead of a shared neutral and installing K factor transformers.

There is power correction equipment out there, but due to financial restrictions, those types of equipment are not available for residential loads.

So check to see if your ballasts are electronic and also check to make sure the polarity is correct on these loads. Make sure you reconnect the bonding jumper. If you are still uncomfortable with this problem, you should bring in someone with the correct metering equipment to verify the problem.

Hope this helps and good luck.

Comment: Doesn't make much sense regarding electronic ballasts having poor power factor. That is true of old magnetic ballasts, which also tend to ground-fault when they get old.  Electronic ballasts use switching power supplies, and it is easy to make them 99+% power factor. The good ones are.  As for ground leakage, fluorescents are typically used in basements, garages and other utility space *where GFCI is also required*.  So again the good ones *can't* leak or they'd be rejected by customers.

Comment: @Harper - It's not about a power factor, it's about causing the neutral load to lag the original voltage and making the return amperage out of phase with the original voltage. Thus creating a harmonic not in sync with the original phase position causing overheating, along with other problems. I can say this has and continues being a larger problem in many industrial and commercial installations. I can also say one of the indicators that this is happening is that the grounding conductors will arc when disconnected.